# MiniTest suite only running two out of 4 testcase files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a TDD solution written in Ruby 1.9.3 (latest stable Windows RubyInstaller).

The application is in the app directory and in the sibling test directory I have 4 files containing tests.

I have a Rakefile executing a MiniTest test suite that merely includes the test case files.
    require 'rake/testtask'

```
Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.test_files = FileList['test/ts_*.rb']
  t.verbose = true
end
```

ts_test_suite.rb:

```
gem 'minitest'
require_relative 'tc_requirement_tests.rb'
require_relative 'tc_command_tests.rb'
require_relative 'tc_movement_tests.rb'
require_relative 'tc_placement_tests.rb'
```

When I execute rake test from the commandline 2 of the 4 files execute successfully and (for some strange reason) the other two are not being executed.  tc_requirement_tests.rb is one of those two files:

```
require 'test_base.rb'
require './app/turn_to.rb'
require './app/direction.rb'

class RequirementTests < TestBase
  def requirement_test_1
    @bad_robot.place(0, 0, Direction::NORTH)
    @bad_robot.move
    assert_equal "Output: 0,1,NORTH", @bad_robot.report_posture
  end

  def requirement_test_2
    @bad_robot.place(0, 0, Direction::NORTH)
    @bad_robot.turn(TurnTo::LEFT)
    assert_equal "Output: 0,0,WEST", @bad_robot.report_posture
  end

  def requirement_test_3
    @bad_robot.place(1, 2, Direction::EAST)
    @bad_robot.move
    @bad_robot.move
    @bad_robot.turn(TurnTo::LEFT)
    @bad_robot.move
    assert_equal "Output: 3,3,NORTH", @bad_robot.report_posture
  end
end
```

If I deliberately put a syntax error in one of the two test case files that are not executing, Rake complains with the expected error message, so I know that it is "seeing" the file.

Any ideas why 2 of the 4 test case files are not being executed?

Comment: What happens if you rename the tests such that they begin with "test_"? I don't know about this particular framework, but other frameworks I've used require test names to begin with "test_"

Comment: Thank Sebastian. All 4 test files begin "tc_".  Only 2 aren't working

Comment: I mean the names of the tests themselves, not the files. Specifically, what happens if you rename the test methods in this particular file to, for instance, "test_requirement_3" "test_requirement_1" etc.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, that was it!  Tests are now executing. If you would like to add this as an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your test framework needs the test function names to begin `test_`. Try renaming your test functions so that they're in the format `test_requirement_1`, `test_requirement_2`, etc.